# How come the result set is different when compared with 8.9 to 2.3 versions of elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Even though the query remains the same in the 2.3 and 8.9 versions of Elastic how come the results will be different?

In the Elastic 8.9 version

```
GET /lems/_search

{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"c_id":{"query":"3M"}}},{"range":{"e_date":{"gte":"09/08/2023","format":"MM/dd/yyyy"}}}]}},"aggregations":{"w_code":{"terms":{"field":"w_code","size":1000}}}}
```

The 8.9 results are:

```
{
    "took": 11,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1704,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "w_code": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "P",
                    "doc_count": 934
                },
                {
                    "key": "Y",
                    "doc_count": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the 2.3 version elastic

```
GET /lems/_search

{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"c_id":{"query":"3M"}}},{"range":{"e_date":{"gte":"09/08/2023","format":"MM/dd/yyyy"}}}]}},"aggregations":{"w_code":{"terms":{"field":"w_code","size":1000}}}}
```

The 2.3 results are:

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 284660,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "lems",
                "_type": "al",
                "_id": "3M466",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "c_id":"3M",
                    "w_code":"E",
                    "e_code": null,
                    "a_id": "1Y01",
                    "e_date": "09/08/2023"
                }
            }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @val could you take on this please?

Comment: can you also share the mappings in each version? Result in 2.3 is missing `aggregations` part, is it?

Comment: 2.3 mapping is  "w_code": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
and 8.9  mapping is 
"w_code": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: @D.T is anything wrong with mapping?